# Error ORA-01403 con trigger en SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, trigger

Recibo un error al intentar insertar datos en una tabla debido a este trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER fechaGasto
BEFORE INSERT ON GASTOS FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE fechaauxiliar DATE;
BEGIN
SELECT FECHAGASTO INTO fechaauxiliar FROM GASTOS WHERE OID_G= :NEW.OID_G;
IF (fechaauxiliar>SYSDATE)
THEN raise_application_error(-20600,:NEW.OID_G||'La fecha introducida no es válida');
END IF;
END;
```

Recibo este error al ejecutar un insert:

```
INSERT INTO GASTOS(OID_G, OID_EMPLEADO, DESCRIPCION, IMPORTE, FECHAGASTO) VALUES(10, 18, 'PUTA MIERDA', 600, '2020-10-22');
```

Error que empieza en la línea: 1 del comando :

```
INSERT INTO GASTOS(OID_G, OID_EMPLEADO, DESCRIPCION, IMPORTE, FECHAGASTO) VALUES(10, 18, 'XXXXX', 600, '2020-10-22')
Informe de error -
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "ISSI1.FECHAGASTO", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ISSI1.FECHAGASTO'
```

Si desactivo el trigger, los datos se introducen sin problema. Pero no soy capaz de entender porque falla el trigger.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

Primero hablemos del error:

### ORA-01403 No data found

El error ORA-01403 significa básicamente que una consulta que debió devolver datos no devuelve ninguno.

En tu caso, el único candidato que veo en el trigger es el `select`:

```
  SELECT FECHAGASTO INTO fechaauxiliar FROM GASTOS WHERE OID_G= :NEW.OID_G;
```

Ocurre que, cuando escribes una consulta `select/into`, esta consulta tiene que devolver **siempre** un registro. No puede devolver más de uno y tampoco puede no devolver registros, ya que ambas situaciones provocan un error: ORA-01403 u ORA-01422.

Si el hecho que no devuelva un registro es un error, corrige el error. Si existe la posibilidad que no lo devuelva, puedes utilizar la construcción `begin/exception/end` para controlar la situación y tomar acción cuando ocurra este error, por ejemplo:

```
  BEGIN
    SELECT FECHAGASTO 
      INTO fechaauxiliar 
      FROM GASTOS 
     WHERE OID_G= :NEW.OID_G;
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    fechaauxiliar := sysdate;
  END;
  IF (fechaauxiliar>SYSDATE)....
```

Ahora, hablemos de tu trigger:

### El problema del trigger que tienes

Para esta sección utilizaré información que veo algo difusa en mi bola de cristal...

Estás escribiendo un trigger `BEFORE INSERT`, lo que significa que se ejecuta **antes** que los datos lleguen a la tabla.

En ese trigger, entiendo que estás intentando hacer una validación sobre los datos a insertar.

No necesitas hacer un `select` para tener acceso a los datos, están todos en el pseudo-registro `new`.  Esta es la razón por la que el select no devuelve ningún valor, puesto que estás intentando consultar un registro que aún no ha llegado a la tabla.

Si lo que he asumido es cierto, tu validación podría reducirse a algo como:

```
  if (:new.FECHAGASTO > SYSDATE) then
    raise_application_error(-20600, :NEW.OID_G||'La fecha introducida no es válida');
  end if;
```