# ORA-01403 No se ha encontrado ningún dato como se soluciona?

Tags: sql, plsql

Estaba practicando pl/sql y me aparece este error, no se porque esta ocurriendo, me ayudan?
Edit: descubrí que no era el error en el trozo de código que postee con anterioridad
sino que es este código el que tienen error y creo que es por el EXTRACT YEAR:

```
SELECT porc_bonif
               INTO v_porc_bonif
               FROM porc_bonif_annos_contrato
               WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM v_reg.fecing_emp) BETWEEN annos_cont_inf AND annos_cont_sup;
               IF EXTRACT (YEAR FROM v_reg.fecing_emp) = 1 THEN 
                    v_porc_bonif:=0;
                    v_asig_annos:=0;
               ELSE
                    v_asig_annos:=ROUND(v_sueldo_base*v_porc_bonif/100);
               END IF;
```

Comment: Parece que v_movilizacion NO es una variable escalar sino de tipo OBJECT o de algún tipo de datos compuesto, lo que PL/SQL denomina "colección".
Habría que mirar la declaración.

Comment: esta declarada como v_movilizacion number;

Comment: Hola WuaFlees. Pon el DECLARE completo para poder ver si existe algún error en la definición

Comment: hola gynch, edite el código arriba porque revise y no era la variable v_movilizacion la que daba problemas sino que el SELECT que esta ahora arriba.

Comment: Hola. El mensaje de error se pone completo en la pregunta, por favor

Comment: Pues el problema es que lo que sea que alimente v_reg o v_porc_bonif posiblemente está obteniendo exactamente cero resultados. Lo realmente curioso es que es después del select into que estás validando lo que tienes en esa variable

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error ORA-01403 con trigger en SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386812/error-ora-01403-con-trigger-en-sql). Sea o no un trigger, es el mismo inconveniente que el mencionado en esta pregunta.